# Placement of adverb "additionally"

Tags: adverbs, adverb-position

["We can put adverbs and adverb phrases at the front, in the middle or at the end of a clause."](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-and-adverb-phrases-position), but where do I put "additionally" in the following sentence?

> 1. If we additionally install Python, the directory structure will look different.

or

> 2. If we install Python additionally, the directory structure will look different.

---

https://www.espressoenglish.net/position-of-adverbs-in-english-sentences/ mentions that "additionally" should come at the front, but the meaning would change here, as

> Additionally, if we install Python, the directory structure will look different.

means "We assume we install Python and then we have an additional property of our system that the directory structure looks different". However, I want to say "We might not install Python, but we definitely install Java. But if we install Python additionally to Java, then the directory structure will look different."

Comment: I wouldn't use "additionally" in that sentence, but one of its synonyms. *If we also install Python*; or *If we install Python as well*.  (For some reason, the best positions for *also* and *as well* are in different places in the sentence.) You could also say: *If we install Python in addition to Java ...*

Comment: @PeterShor: Do you know what the rule is for "also", "as well" and possibly "additionally"?

Comment: I can tell you where adverbs go in any individual sentence; I can't actually write down the rules; i only know them instinctively.

Comment: It depends on the preceding sentence(s). If you have been discussing installing another thing, then you might say "Additionally, ..."

Comment: There is no "the rule" for adverbs. They are flexible in their position because they don't indicate arguments in the sentence, but rather modifications of something -- though rarely of a single word, hence their flexible placement. Adverbs -- especially pragmatic ones like _additionally_ -- help link sentences and thoughts together, and that can be done in many ways, where words-in-a-row "rules" just get in the way.